# How to use CHRG pin for voltage detector instead of LED

Tags: power, battery-charging

I have a power management IC (SLM4055) that has a CHRG pin that goes to LOW when charging then HIGH (5V) when full. Normally used with LED indicator like this other one:

[image]

I would like to replace the LED with a voltage divider then read the voltage (interrupt) on an IC rated to 3.3 V. But I noticed when battery is full then it will go to HIGH so the voltage divider won't work any more; I receive 5V then my IC will fry.

I thought of adding a component capable of limiting the voltage (zener diode, voltage comparator), but I was not really able to find anything simple...

Since I met MOSFETs, I've been putting them everywhere, so I design my own:

[image]

When simulating it appears to be working, my tests were successful: it receives 3 V change when charging and pass to almost null when full.

I just would like you to check if all is good.

But when it goes to HIGH I noticed some kind of leakage on the IC (pin 1 and ground), I tested by adding diodes around but I don't know where it comes from. Anyway, it's negligible (49 mV).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [TP4056 datasheet](http://www.tp4056.com/datasheet/) the CHRG and STDBY pins are pulled low when they're active and go into high impedance state when they're not:

[image]

So a simple pullup resistor to your 3.3V supply is all that's needed.

(NOTE: Even if the pin did go to 5V in the off state, a simple voltage divider formed by a pair of resistors would be more than adequate)

Comment: sorry for confusion, I'm actually using SLM4055 (found only chinese datasheet) which pulled low then charging and High when full. But should work with the same principe.